# integral of min of delta functions

Tags: probability, integration, dirac-delta

Show that for some $\rho>0$

$$ \inf_{|z| \leq \rho} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (r \delta(x-k) \land  r \delta(x+z-k)) \ \textrm{d}x >0$$

where $r,k,z>0$?

I am not sure how to deal with the ∧ operator and the delta functions. Thanks for your help!

*Edit*: I solved my own question (see below). The inequality is never satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the inequality is never satisfied.

$$ \inf_{|z| \leq \rho} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (r \delta(x-k) \land  r \delta(x+z-k)) \ \textrm{d}x >0$$

$$  = \inf_{|z| \leq \rho} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \min{(r \delta(x-k), r \delta(x+z-k))} \ \textrm{d}x >0$$

The minimum of two delta functions with always be zero unless they are the centered at the same point, i.e. $z=0$. Then
$$\inf_{|z| \leq \rho} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (r \delta(x-k) \land  r \delta(x+z-k)) \ \textrm{d}x =\inf_{|z| \leq \rho} r\mathbb{1}_z$$
where
$$ \mathbb{1}_z = \begin{cases} 1 & z=0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

which is always zero.